# How to manage directories in hdfs with a bash script?

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs

Recently I tried to write a bash script to manage some directory in hdfs in order to work with kafka.

suppose that in hdfs we have a directory like this:

```
/tmp/my_dir/state=a
```

when I list this directory with `hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/my_dir/state=a` the result is:

```
part=2020-05-10
part=2020-05-11
.
.
.
part=2020-05-20
```

each folder contains some files, and I want to divide these folders into two directory base on a specific date.

my goal is to create two directories which are `version=1` and `version=2` and I want to move every part folder to this two directory, base on a specific date, so all part folder with smaller date goes to

```
/tmp/my_dir/version=1/state=a
```

and the other ones go to

```
/tmp/my_dir/version=2/state=a
```

I prepare this code but it doesn't work correctly.
can anyone help me to correct it?

```
for fullname in `hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/my_dir/state=a | awk '{print $NF}' | grep part | tr '\n' ' '`; do

    name=$(basename $fullname)

    if [[ "${name#*=}" < "$selected_date" ]]; then

        hdfs dfs -mv $fullname /tmp/my_dir/version=1/state=a

    else
        hdfs dfs -mv $fullname /tmp/my_dir/version=2/state=a
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem!

It is just because I didn't create internal directories and I should use this command before loop instruction:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp/my_dir/version=1
hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp/my_dir/version=2

hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp/my_dir/version=1/state=a
hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp/my_dir/version=2/state=a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually achieve this with a single command by providing `-p` flag for `mkdir`:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p version=1/state=a version=2/state=a
```

---

As a general advise, I would recommend to use a better naming convention. In this particular case, `v1/state_a/` and `v2/state_a/` would be appropriate (or even `v1/state/a/`).